# Isolation Level Trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a doubt about how isolation level in a Trigger works.

I have to perform an Insert on a Table and I need to do some checks before the insert.

For this Reason I have a Trigger "before insert" that compare some values.

I need block the tables in order to block others insert , do the check , insert the new row and then unlock the table.

In order to do it , if I have a Trigger with isolation level serializable , the lock on  the table will be released only after the new insert?

Comment: *I have to perform an Insert on a Table and I need to do some checks before the insert.* In most cases all needed checks may be performed in WHERE clause of the INSERT query (use INSERT .. SELECT, of course). Without a trigger. *a Trigger with isolation level serializable* If this is not default isolation level then wrap your INSERT into explicit transaction with needed level.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing [SERIALIZABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html) does in MySQL is makes `SELECT` into `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE` if you are not using autocommit.  This does not lock the whole table.

If you need to block concurrent inserts, then use [LOCK TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html). You are responsible for unlocking explicitly, or else there's an implicit unlock tables if you start a new transaction.

But you can't use `LOCK TABLES` inside a trigger. You'll have to do it before attempting your `INSERT`.